# Swing not repainting when I run the .jar except in command prompt

Tags: java, swing, jar, cardlayout

I have a project with a lot of panels. I have one method that switches the card (jpanel) in a card layout panel (see below). This all works fine when I run it from my IDE (Netbeans) and when I run the jar from command prompt (`java -jar MyStuff.jar`). But when I double click the Jar the card changes but doesn't `repaint` producing undesireable results (when I mouse over the components appear). If I call the method again by clicking the button again it'll apply. I need help immediately please :) Thanks!

```
/**
* Shows a panel by the given panel name (in the cardPanel)
*
* @param panelName
*/
private void showPanel(String panelName) {
  if (panelName.equals("revenueSources")) {
    backButtonIcon.setVisible(false);
  } else {
    backButtonIcon.setVisible(true);
  }
  currentPanelName = panelName;
  ((CardLayout) cardPanel.getLayout()).show(cardPanel, panelName);
  repaint();
  revalidate();
}
```

Comment: very well, could be nice question in the case edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: This [SSCCE using `CardLayout`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556) works without calling `repaint()`, `revalidate()` *or* 
`validate()`.  I can only conclude that your code is very wrong.  But I'll reserve further comment for ***your*** SSCCE.

Comment: You're right, I'm wrong to not use SSCCE. I just don't have time and in a few hours it wont matter. I'll just use a bat file to run it instead. Thanks for the help.

Comment: And of course you call this method on the EDT ?

Comment: Yeah, there's a button that starts the method.

Comment: If you don't have the time to create an sscce, then neither do we. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(when I mouse over the components appear)` for this code only swap from

```
repaint();
revalidate();
```

to

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: @kentcdodds: if it didn't work, then you may wish to create and post your [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: +1, I will go with the answer :-), just couldn't understand the call to `repaint()/revalidate()` by OP, that too in CardLayout :-)